# Glossaries always gives last entry of csv-list when processed with datatool

Tags: glossaries, datatool, csv

Ok, I am clearly missing something but I cannot figure out what is wrong.
All is fine concerning the `\gls{}`-entries, but in `\printglossary` I only get the last entry of the `.csv`-list.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{datatool}    
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{emperor.csv}
  Kaiser, Name, Geburt, Tod, Regierungszeit
  Augustus,Imperator Caesar Divi Filius Augustus,*23.September 63 v.Chr. in Rom,† 19. August 14 n.Chr. in Nola,vom 16. Jan. 27 v.Chr. bis 19. August 14 n.Chr.
  Tiberius,Tiberius Claudius Nero,*16. November 42 v.Chr. in Rom,† 16. März 37 n. Chr. in Misenum,vom 19. August 14 v.Chr. bis 16. März 37 n.Chr.
  Caligula,Gaius Caesar Augustus Germanicus,*31. August 12 in Antium,† 24. Jan. 41 in Rom (ermordet),vom 18. März 37 bis 24. Jan. 41
  Claudius,Tiberius Claudius Nero Germanicus,* 1. August 10 v.Chr. in Lugdunum,† 13. Oktober 54 n.Chr. in Rom,vom 24. Jan. 41 bis 13. Oktober 54
  Nero,Nero Claudius Caesar Drusus Germanicus,* 15. Dezember 37 in Antium,† 9. Juni 68 in Rom (Selbstmord),vom 13. Oktober 54 bis 9. Juni 68
\end{filecontents}    
\makeglossaries

\DTLloaddb{romanemperors}{emperor.csv}
 \glssetexpandfield{Kaiser}
\glssetexpandfield{Name}
\glssetexpandfield{Geburt}
\glssetexpandfield{Tod}
\glssetexpandfield{Regierungszeit}

\DTLforeach*{romanemperors}% data set
 {\Kaiser=Kaiser,%
  \Name=Name,%
  \Geburt=Geburt,%
  \Tod=Tod,%
  \Regierungszeit=Regierungszeit% 
 }{%
\newglossaryentry{\Kaiser}{%
   name={\textbf{\Kaiser}}, 
   description={\Kaiser\ 
     \ifdefempty{\Name}{}{(\Name)} 
       -- \Regierungszeit;\newline
      \Geburt\newline
      \Tod}, 
   first={\Kaiser\ (\Name; Kaiser \Regierungszeit)},%
  }}
\newcommand*{\glstype}{\glssymbol}

\begin{document}
  Hallo Kaiser \gls{Caligula}\par
  \gls{Caligula}

\printglossary[
  title = {Namen und Daten der römischen Kaiser},
] 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of `\glssetexpandfield` must be the internal field label used by the `glossaries` package (see [Table 4.1: Key to Field Mappings](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#tab:fieldmap) in the user manual). In this case `name`, `desc` and `first`. You've used the `datatool` keys instead (`Kaiser`, `Name` etc).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{datatool}    
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{emperor.csv}
  Kaiser, Name, Geburt, Tod, Regierungszeit
  Augustus,Imperator Caesar Divi Filius Augustus,*23.September 63 v.Chr. in Rom,† 19. August 14 n.Chr. in Nola,vom 16. Jan. 27 v.Chr. bis 19. August 14 n.Chr.
  Tiberius,Tiberius Claudius Nero,*16. November 42 v.Chr. in Rom,† 16. März 37 n. Chr. in Misenum,vom 19. August 14 v.Chr. bis 16. März 37 n.Chr.
  Caligula,Gaius Caesar Augustus Germanicus,*31. August 12 in Antium,† 24. Jan. 41 in Rom (ermordet),vom 18. März 37 bis 24. Jan. 41
  Claudius,Tiberius Claudius Nero Germanicus,* 1. August 10 v.Chr. in Lugdunum,† 13. Oktober 54 n.Chr. in Rom,vom 24. Jan. 41 bis 13. Oktober 54
  Nero,Nero Claudius Caesar Drusus Germanicus,* 15. Dezember 37 in Antium,† 9. Juni 68 in Rom (Selbstmord),vom 13. Oktober 54 bis 9. Juni 68
\end{filecontents}    
\makeglossaries

\DTLloaddb{romanemperors}{emperor.csv}
\glssetexpandfield{name}
\glssetexpandfield{desc}
\glssetexpandfield{first}

\DTLforeach*{romanemperors}% data set
 {\Kaiser=Kaiser,%
  \Name=Name,%
  \Geburt=Geburt,%
  \Tod=Tod,%
  \Regierungszeit=Regierungszeit% 
 }{%
\newglossaryentry{\Kaiser}{%
   name={\textbf{\Kaiser}}, 
   description={\Kaiser\ 
     \ifdefempty{\Name}{}{(\Name)} 
       -- \Regierungszeit;\newline
      \Geburt\newline
      \Tod}, 
   first={\Kaiser\ (\Name; Kaiser \Regierungszeit)},%
  }}
\newcommand*{\glstype}{\glssymbol}

\begin{document}
  Hallo Kaiser \gls{Caligula}\par
  \gls{Caligula}

\printglossary[
  title = {Namen und Daten der römischen Kaiser},
] 

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]